# No querystring logged in IIS log on "A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value detected"

Tags: asp.net, security, query-string, iis-logs

I'm intermittently seeing this exception being thrown:

> A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value detected

However when I look in the IIS logs I can see that the request that failed has no querystring logged against it.

How could this be?  Are "dangerous" query strings being stripped from the log or something?

Comment: I wonder how an id=5555 could be considered potentially dangerous. any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure that IIS would store a potentially dangerous querystring parameter - unless it didn't recognise it as such.

If you download and run [NetSparker (free Community edition)](http://www.mavitunasecurity.com/communityedition/) you can find which URLs on your site are vulnerable and examples of querystrings that will cause IIS to record the error.

An example of a 'dangerous' querystring is if a url like the following causes an Internal Error Message; you can cause the error to appear in IIS like this if youe want:

```
http://your-site.com/your-url?nsextt='"--><script>netsparker(0x00000F)</script>
```

Netsparker* considers this a low severity issue, with the following impact:

> The impact may vary depending on the
>   condition. This might be an indication
>   of a bigger issue such as SQL
>   Injection or could be the result or
>   poor coding practices.

**I use NetSparker - no other connection.*

Answer (score 1):

You want to look a level higher in the logging, check the `%WINDIR%\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR` folder.